Software To Manage a Music Performing Group
I manage a music performing group and I’m really hoping there’s software out there already that can help me do what I do better. The way my business works is that performance venues contact me to book our music group to perform on a certain date or dates. I then reach out to all of the musicians in the group to check their availability and they (hopefully quickly) give me a yes/no/maybe response on their availability. If I have enough availability to do the performance, we create a booking and a contract for performing (along with collecting a booking fee/deposit), and the musicians get “assigned” to that performance. Not all of the musicians are assigned to a given performance…only some of them. Then as we get closer to the performance date, I coordinate communications/reminders/notifications with both the venue contact and the assigned performers. The venue has a final $$ balance that is due on the day of the performance that needs to be collected. Afterward, the musicians need to be paid from those funds.
So I’m looking for a plugin to help with as much of that as possible. Pie in the sky it would help me track:

Venues (and their contact person)
Performance dates/times
Musicians (and assignments of them to performances)
Availability of musicians
Invoices to Venues
Payments for Musicians
Notifications to both Musicians and Venues (ideally SMS text
communications to musicians)

Thanks in advance for any advice!
